# slect same value from different column

Tags: mysql

I have to insert in data2 the value of data1 only if id1 is equal to id2, even if in different rows.

MySql

```
Example
    +---------------------------+
    |          MyTable          |
    +---------------------------+
    | id1 | id2 | data1 | data2 |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  1  |  2  | data1 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  2  |  1  | data2 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  3  |  4  | data3 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  4  |  3  | data4 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  5  |  6  | data5 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
```

this is an example of the result

```
    +---------------------------+
    |          MyTable          |
    +---------------------------+
    | id1 | id2 | data1 | data2 |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  1  |  2  | data1 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  2  |  1  | data2 | data1 |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  3  |  4  | data3 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  4  |  3  | data4 | data3 |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+
    |  5  |  6  | data5 |   0   |
    +-----+-----+-------+-------+


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `id1` int(6) NULL,
  `id2` int(6) NULL,
  `data1` varchar(50) NULL,
  `data2` varchar(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id1`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`id1`, `id2`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES
  ('1', '2', 'data1','0' ),
  ('2', '1', 'data2','0'),
  ('3', '4', 'data3','0'),
  ('4', '3', 'data4','0'),
  ('5', '6', 'data5','0');
```

maybe there are other solutions without using COALESCE (), also to exclude lines that have id2 equal to id1 and include only those that have id1 equal to id2

```
  SELECT
  t1.id1, 
  t1.id2, 
  t1.data1, 
  COALESCE(t2.data1, t1.data2) AS `data2`
FROM MyTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS t2
  ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND 
     t1.id2 = t2.id1 

Result
id1 id2 data1   data2
1   2   data1   data2
2   1   data2   data1
3   4   data3   data4
4   3   data4   data3
5   6   data5   0
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a good place to come asking for others to do your work for you. You should state your issue in the form of a question, including details abut what you've already tried and any failures or error messages you've seen. Share your thoughts on what could be wrong if appropriate. See [how do i ask a  good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a "Self Left Join" matching `id1` with `id2` of the right-side table, and vice versa.

If there is a match (even in different row), the right side table `data1` will not be `null`. We can then use it instead of `data2`.

```
SELECT
  t1.id1, 
  t1.id2, 
  t1.data1, 
  COALESCE(t2.data1, t1.data2) AS `data2`
FROM your_table AS t1
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t2
  ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND 
     t1.id2 = t2.id1
```

Comment: Thanks Madhur, I tried your solution but without result

Comment: @GT73 there was a typo. Instead of t1 it was to be t2 at one place. Please check the updated answer.  Is there a primary key in your table ?

Comment: this has now worked. It works on both lines but that's okay. I do not have a primary key, this is a view of multiple tables. id1 is a primary key of another table. However now I understood where I was wrong, thank you.